Why does sympy.perfect_power(-64) return False?
The documentation for sympy.perfect_power says:

Return (b, e) such that n == b**e if n is a unique perfect power with e > 1, else False (e.g. 1 is not a perfect power). A ValueError is raised if n is not Rational.

Yet evaluating sympy.perfect_power(-64) results in False. However, -64 == (-4)**3, so sympy.perfect_power(-64) should return (-4, 3) (also because there is no other integer base with integer exponent > 1).
Is this a bug? Or am I missing something here?

I know I'm off-topic here, but while I see that that function will permit negative perfect powers, can a negative number be a perfect power? The Wikipedia article indicates that b and e (and by extension all perfect powers) have to be positive... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power

@SimonMᶜKenzie the link in my post says that perfect_power(-8) returns (-2, 3). So negative numbers can be perfect powers.

Wolfram also indicates that perfect powers are always positive. I'm not a mathematician, but it seems to me that the function's behaviour and documentation may be incorrect, and that all negative input to the function should return false. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectPower.html

Given the example of perfect_power(-8) returning (-2, 3), it's hard not to view this as a bug.  It may be that it's first finding (2, 6), then seeing if the exponent is odd, and since it isn't, giving up, when in fact it should go to (4, 3), note that the exponent is odd, and finally adjust it to (-4, 3).

@TomKarzes This actually makes for an interesting observation: something like perfect_power(-16) should still return False. Generally: perfect_power(-2**n) for positive integer n should return False iff n is a power of 2 (including 1).

It is a bug: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/27238. It would have been better if perfect_power rejected negative inputs but if it accepts them then it needs to do so consistently.

This issue has been corrected in the development branch of SymPy.

At the documentation, click on [source] and you'll find this:
    if n < 0:
        pp = perfect_power(-n)
        if pp:
            b, e = pp
            if e % 2:
                return -b, e
        return False

Given -64, that first computes that 64 is 2^6 and then gives up because 6 isn't odd.
I do think it's a bug and it should try to remove the factor 2 from the exponent. Maybe like this:
    if n < 0:
        pp = perfect_power(-n)
        if pp:
            b, e = pp
            e2 = e & -e
            if e2 != e:
                return -(b**e2), e//e2
        return False

